# Get all double quote characters outside of string enclosed within special characters « and »

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to get all the double quotes from all the substrings which are outside the enclosing  characters « and » and replace them with escape character followed by double quote ie. \" For an example

Input String:

```
'The first generally recognized "wiki" application,«"WikiWikiWeb"», was created by American computer programmer "Ward Cunningham" in 1994'
```

Expected Output:

```
'The first generally recognized \"wiki\" application,«"WikiWikiWeb"», was created by American computer programmer \"Ward Cunningham\" in 1994'
```

I tried following code.

```
string = '''The first generally recognized "wiki" application,«"WikiWikiWeb"», was created by American computer programmer "Ward Cunningham" in 1994'''

import re
arr = re.findall(r'(.*?)\«.*?\»', string)
for tag in arr :
 new_tag = tag.replace('"','\\"')
 string = string.replace(tag, new_tag)

Output: The first generally recognized \"wiki\" application,«"WikiWikiWeb"», was created by American computer programmer "Ward Cunningham" in 1994
```

The issue with this code is the regex is not giving me all the substrings, in this case the second substring ie. the expected result must be:

['The first generally recognized "wiki" application',', was created by American computer programmer "Ward Cunningham" in 1994' ].

I want regex which should give me all the quotes from the substring instead of the substrings itself which are outside the enclosing special characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string = '''The first generally recognized "wiki" application,«blah"WikiWikiWeb"blah», was created by American computer programmer "Ward Cunningham" in 1994'''

import re
arr = re.findall(r'«.*?»|(".+?")', string)
for tag in arr :
  new_tag = tag.replace('"','\\"')
  string = string.replace(tag, new_tag)

print string
```

**Output:**

```
The first generally recognized \"wiki\" application,«blah"WikiWikiWeb"blah», was created by American computer programmer \"Ward Cunningham\" in 1994
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern for regex :

```
string = re.sub(r'(?<!\«)"(?!\»)','\\"',string)
```

`(?<!«)` is Negative Lookbehind which means find " that not followed by «
and
`(?!»)` is a Negative lookahead which has the same effect but works backward

Comment: @SheetalJagtap:  It doesn't work if there are characters between `«` and `"` like `«blah"text"blah»`